Getting date into modal form in appscript
There is an edit data button on the index page. When I click on the edit button, I want the date format to appear as dd.mm.yyyy. How can I adjust the date format? For example, it says 30.06.2024 in the e-table, but the data does not come to the modal form.
Function in Code.gs file
function formatDate(date) {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+3', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
  return formattedDate;
}

function getEmployeeData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PERSONEL');
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 9).getDisplayValues();
  return data.map(function(row, index) {
    return {
      id: index + 2,
      tcKimlik: row[0],
      adSoyad: row[1],
      magazaAdi: row[2],
      iseGirisTarihi: formatDate(new Date(row[3])),
      stajyerEvrak: row[4] === 'TRUE',
      sgkBildirim: row[5] === 'TRUE',
      sozlesme: row[6] === 'TRUE',
      ozlukDosyasi: row[7] === 'TRUE',
      iseGirisTeyit: row[8] === 'TRUE'
    };
  });
}

index.html file,
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="ise-giris-tarihi" class="form-label">İŞE GİRİŞ TARİHİ</label>
  <input type="date" id="ise-giris-tarihi" class="form-control">
</div>

Data coming from the table to the modal form for editing in the table
editButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const id = button.getAttribute('data-id');
    currentEditId = id;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(employee) {

      document.getElementById('ise-giris-tarihi').value = employee.iseGirisTarihi;

      const employeeModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('employee-modal'));
      employeeModal.show();
    }).getEmployeeById(id);
  });
});

